# margin issue when resize page or emulate

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple layout based on 960px fixed width and the margin is `margin: 0 auto;` to let it be in the center of the page.

When I try to stretch the browser window to 960px automatically the margin change to `margin: 0 10px;` and it looks bad.

Why I'm having this problem?

Please find the image below to see what happen:

[image]

Comment: Mind posting all of your code so we could analyse the problem more thoroughly, rather than having to guess by just a glimpse of the larger picture?

Comment: one div, a reset css (bootstrap one), a single row of css.